# Is there a way to know the values of arguments passed to function?

Tags: python

we can know the name of the function with func.**name**, is there such a simple for knowing the values that were passed?

```
import time


def warn_slow(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
       start_time=time.time()
       func(*args,**kwargs)
       time_elapsed=time.time()-start_time
       if time_elapsed>2:
            return (f"execution of {func.__name__} with {arguments values} arguments took more than 2 seconds")
    return wrapper
```

I want to write a decorator that will return a message containing argument values when the execution took more than 2 seconds

Comment: What's wrong with `print(args)` / `return args`?

Comment: the `args` and `kwargs` are just what you want.

Comment: Please give examples of some arguments that you pass that you want to know the values of.

Comment: when trying *args Syntax error arises with the message "can't use starred expression here"

Answer (score 1):

I would do it following way:

```
return (f"execution of {func.__name__} with arguments {args} and keyword arguments {kwargs} took more than 2 seconds")
```

You might elect to improve it changing what is return in case there are not `args` and in case there are not `kwargs`.